# Why keys are not merged with "WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" using maven-war-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, maven-war-plugin

I am building an application and then merging some custom keys in the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
        <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
        <Build-Revision>${buildNumber}</Build-Revision>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have 2 profiles, the production profile uses the following resource config:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <!-- "all" is used for all profiles, "development" and "production" -->
        <directory>src/main/resources/all</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <!-- "prod" is just used for "production" -->
        <directory>src/main/resources/prod</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

A default MANIFEST.MF is located at `src/main/resources/all/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, which should be used as a base.

**What do I expect?**

I expect that the MANIFEST.MF is available at `myproject.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with "Build-Time" and "Build-Revision" updated according to the values provided. Then I will be able to access the MANIFEST.MF file at runtime to retrieve the "Build-Revision" key and handle caching stuff.

**What happens instead?**

What happens instead is that the MANIFEST.MF is created inside `myproject.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with the values updated, and in the `WEB-INF` location there is just a copy of the MANIFEST.MF without any key updated.

**Why does WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is not updated through maven-war-plugin?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I figured it out, it was my ignorance of how maven handles `src/main/resources` and the manifest file)

Maven creates a proper `MANIFEST.MF` file inside `META-INF/` and uses it as the default convention path for a manifest, there is no need to create another one inside the `src/main/resources` folder, the default should be in the root.

If you remove the MANIFEST from `src/main/resources` (which would be copied to `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) you will have only one and will be able to access the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` from the application using:

```
request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream( "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" );
```